# \begin{titlepage} environment or equivalent in KOMA

Tags: koma-script

I am looking for a way to freely build a title page in an scrartcl just as I used to do in classic articles by using `\begin{titlepage}`...`\end{titlepage}` or a close equivalent.

Specifics:

- Reuse old code: The title pages are written and proved to be working in standard article format documents. I would like to completely recycle them out of their environments and place them in a scrartl.
- Generic packages from TeX Live: I know there is the `titlepage` package that can be downloaded from KOMA website but there must be a way to do this out of the box. I can not require my users to install software from outside their package managers.

Is there really no way KOMA allows us to define an entirely custom title page and not make use of their automatisms?

For now I tried to define a `\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}` with `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`, use it on the first page by `\thispagestyle{firstpage}`, then do `\pagestyle{otherpages}` for the rest of the document. This weirdly fails by telling me `Can be used only in preamble. \clearpage` on the first usage of `\clearpage`. One of those odd TeX errors that typically let you know you are on the wrong way of thinking.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't use `\begin{titlepage}…\end{titlepage}` in a KOMA-Script document. This works perfectly fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}\par
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
        {\Huge Put a Pretty Portion of Paragraphs\\on Pages Preferred by Printers\par}
        \vspace{2\baselineskip}
        {\Large A Study on the\\Marvels of Human Incompetence\par}
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
        {\large\textsc{by\\[.5em]A. N. Onym}}
        \vfill
        A Work of Exceptional Intelligence produced\\ to become a Doctor of Philosophy at the\\[1em]
        {\em University of Applied Balderdash}
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image: title page]

Comment: Defining a new style and then `\thispagestyle{firstpage}` was the problem. Even an empty definition would not be accepted there. Whereas `\thispagestyle{empty}` does the job. Your answer kept me on trying to make `\begin{titlepage}` work, otherwise I would have abandoned it. Thanks! Also saves me the work of debugging my style definition now.

Comment: @harmonica141, glad to hear (or better read) it! The best of luck with your project!